# Table (words and numerical values) and generating text File

Tags: python

I am trying to write a table in Python but am unable to get the right outcome.

I am trying to get this output:

[image]

I am using the following code:

```
nestedlist = [["Point 1",0,5,0],
              ["Point 2",0,0,0],
              ["Point 3",5,0,0],
              ["Point 4",5,5,0],]
print("n x y z")
for item in nestedlist:
        print(item[0], item[1], item[2], item[3])
```

I am getting output:

[image]

Also, how can I link this to text file generation?

```
with open("myfile.txt","w") as file:
    file.write("data inside file.")
```

Comment: Please include the desired and actual output as text, not as images.

Comment: Your output is exactly what is expected from the code. `print(a, b)` will only insert a single space between them. If you want to visually format it like a "table", you need to set the same width to all items, so that there is padding like in your desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tabulate` to achieve both of your goals.

**Option #1**

Just printing your table:

```
print(tabulate(nestedlist, headers=['n','x','y','z'],tablefmt="plain"))
```

**Note:** *`tablefmt="plain"` --> tables do not use any pseudo-graphics to draw lines:*
Output:

```
n          x    y    z
Point 1    0    5    0
Point 2    0    0    0
Point 3    5    0    0
Point 4    5    5    0
```

**Option #2**

Write your table to an `.txt` file:

```
with open('table.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(tabulate(nestedlist, headers=['n','x','y','z'],tablefmt="plain"))
```

#### Example

```
from tabulate import tabulate

nestedlist = [["Point 1",0,5,0],
             ["Point 2",0,0,0],
             ["Point 3",5,0,0],
             ["Point 4",5,5,0],]

with open('table.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(tabulate(nestedlist, headers=['n','x','y','z'],tablefmt="plain"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve string padding with the standard library string method `string_variable.ljust(width)` below is an example -

```
points_list = [["Point 1",0,5,0],
             ["Point 2",0,0,0],
             ["Point 3",5,0,0],
             ["Point 4",5,5,0],]
heading=["n", "x", "y", "z"]

result = ""

padding_width = 10
for string in heading:
    result = result + str(string).ljust(padding_width)

for nested_list in points_list:
    result = result + '\n'
    for string in nested_list:
        result = result + str(string).ljust(padding_width)

print(result)

with open("myfile.txt","w") as file:
    file.write(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
column_headers = ["n", "x", "y", "z"]
nestedlist = [["Point 1",0,5,0],
             ["Point 2",0,0,0],
             ["Point 3",5,0,0],
             ["Point 4",5,5,0],]

print("{:<10} {:<10} {:<10} {:<10}".format(*column_headers))
for row in nestedlist:
    print("{:<10} {:<10} {:<10} {:<10}".format(*row))

# print out table...
```

To save it to a text file try this:

```
with open("myfile.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("{:<10} {:<10} {:<10} {:<10}\n".format(*column_headers))
    for row in nestedlist:
        f.write("{:<10} {:<10} {:<10} {:<10}\n".format(*row))
```

Comment: While this code *may* answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: Thank you @martineau. I had some time and wanted to help, but you are absolutely correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The `tabulate` library is very handy for this sort of thing:

```
from tabulate import tabulate

nestedlist = [["Point 1",0,5,0],
            ["Point 2",0,0,0],
            ["Point 3",5,0,0],
            ["Point 4",5,5,0],]
my_headers = "n x y z".split()

my_output = tabulate(nestedlist, headers=my_headers)
print(my_output)
```

Output:

```
n          x    y    z
-------  ---  ---  ---
Point 1    0    5    0
Point 2    0    0    0
Point 3    5    0    0
Point 4    5    5    0
```

You can also write `my_output` to a text file and it'll be formatted in the same way.

See the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/) for how to customize the formatting if required.